# Handle module not found in laravel 7 routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-routing

let's say I have some

```
Route::get('/path/{model}', 'Controller@method');
```

In the case of `mysite.com/path/1` & no Model#1, I getting 404 which is default Laravel behavior
I want to handle (basically, redirect to another named route) "NoModelFound" for **specific group of routes / specific route**

As this route exists, `Route::fallback` or `Route::any` will not trigger here.

I know there is a `Route()->missing` method in Laravel 8, but I have Laravel 7 and can't update.
Also, in the best way, I search for solutions within routes ( `web.php` )

Is any solution for this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can globally handle exception in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. If you really and i mean really want to be specific about handling `ModelNotFoundException` for only certain routes then you can do some thing like

```
  // Exception Handle class
  public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
       
        if(
            $request->is('*path/') &&  // or string match
            $exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException
        ){
            redirect()->to('where-ever');
        }
    }
```

If you just want to redirect user whenever `ModelNotFoundException` occurs then you could do this,

```
  // Exception Handle class
  public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
       
        if(
            
            $exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException
        ){
            redirect()->to('where-ever');
        }
    }
```

Another way would be to use a middleware and check for certain model, if it doesnt exist, then redirect the user. Depends on what you are trying to do. You can find more information here

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#the-exception-handler